# AngularJS display JSON data in table

Tags: json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS with RESTAPI, I am able to get the customers data sent from server in a JSON format. My Angular code snippet as below:

```
  app.factory("services", ['$http', function($http) {
  var serviceBase = '/api/album';
    var obj = {};
    obj.getCustomers = function(){
        return $http.get(serviceBase);
    };
    return obj;   
}]);
    app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
services.getCustomers().then(function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
    $scope.customers = data.data;
    });
});
```

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "artist": "Gotye75",
        "title": "Making  Mirrors7"
    },
    {
        "id": "100",
        "artist": "ytttt5",
        "title": "1231"
    },
    {
        "id": "101",
        "artist": "65",
        "title": "565444555"
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "artist": "6",
        "title": "6"
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "artist": "y",
        "title": "yy"
    },
    {
        "id": "104",
        "artist": "ty",
        "title": "yt"
    },
    {
        "id": "109",
        "artist": "ytrer",
        "title": "yt"
    }
    ]
}
```

I am able to display the JSON data in table if my JSON does not contain the "data" hear. However if my jSON data comes with "data" header, it is unable to display. I am asking, what are the solution in Angular to parse the JSON object.

For example if it is in BackboneJS, i can simply do

```
    parse: function (response) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    return response.data;
}
```

How can i do it in Angular?

Answer (score 4):

`$http` resolves its promises with a response object. The data is accessed via the response object's data property. So to get to the array, you'd have to use

```
$scope.customers = data.data.data;
```

`$http`'s promise is enhanced with a `.success()` convenience method which unwraps the response object...

```
services.getCustomers().success(function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
    $scope.customers = data.data;
});
```

Comment: How can I add exception/error handling to my promises in controller of this kind, DataService.getDataUsingPromises()
.then(function(data) {
 $scope.netspendovertime_data = data;
 });. And In my services I have return $q.when(originalRequest)
 .then(function(res) {
 data = res.ResultSet.Response;
 return data;
});

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
    services.getCustomers().then(function(data){
    //notice that i added the third data
    $scope.customers = data.data.data;
    }); 
});
```